# PDF Outlook Email attachment sometimes saved with no permissions

Tags: c#, pdf, outlook, email-attachments

Looping through messages (getItem object) in an Outlook message store and saving attachments as files  using the code below:

```
try 
{
      foreach (Outlook.Attachment attach in getItem.Attachments)
      {
           if (attach.FileName == sItemName)
           {
                string sSaveFile = Path.GetTempPath() + "Attachment" + sItemType;
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(sSaveFile)) System.IO.File.Delete(sSaveFile);
                attach.SaveAsFile(sSaveFile);
                sContent = Common.GetFileContent2(sSaveFile);
           }
      }
 }
 catch (Exception Ex)
 {
      Common.LogError("GetUpdated", Ex, "Get text from Email attachment", "Error", false);
 }
 System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(getItem.Attachments);
```

I find that the extracted PDF file is sometimes inaccessible for deletion when another PDF file appears. The file permissions of the extracted PDF file cannot be viewed in Explorer - the Security tab of properties says "You must have read permissions to view the properties of this object". The General properties tab can be read OK.

I am using Outlook 2007 in Windows 8.1

Comment: What file path is used in the code? Do you run Outlook with admin privileges?

Comment: The path to the save folder  is the user Temp directory which is C:\User\AppData\Local\Temp. I have tried reinstalling Office without success as suggested by someone else with a similar problem. Outlook is not run with any privileges. It is invoked with
     `Outlook.Application myApp = new Outlook.Application();
                                Outlook.NameSpace mapiNameSpace =     myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");`. The failure to delete the file occurs with no discernable pattern and only occurs for PDFs. The permissionless PDFS disappear after about 90 secs

Comment: I don't see anything strange in the code. Try to run it on another PCs. Do you get the same results? Do you have any antivirus software on the problematic PC?

Comment: I have Windows Defender (MsMpEng.exe) as AV/ Anti-malware. Running on another PC is hard as I only have Visual Studio on one machine, but other executables running on another machine (Win 7, Office 2010) have not shown any problem

Comment: Most probably your system is corrupted in some way. Because I couldn't reproduce the issue on my PC with Windows 8.1. Do you have the latest updates and service packs installed to Outlook 2007?

Comment: Outlook 2007 version is 12.0.6691.5000 SP3 MSO (12.0.6718.5000), and the latest Office 2007 update was today so I presume it is up to date. When running the code again, the same PDF attachment to the same emails fail to save, but there does not seem to any indication of whether  PDF attachments save successfully or not. Failures and successes occur with with messages in all Outlook folders. The save problem was not present a few months ago, and may be connected with on Outlook update.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue on any other PC?

Comment: Running the compiled code on Win 7 machine with Outlook 2010 the problem does not appear, so I think it may specific to Outlook 2007

Comment: Problem has reappeared after a temporary disappearance after upgrading to Outlook 2010 so it's not an Outlook 2007 problem.

Comment: Do you have any antivirus software installed on the PC?

Comment: Windows Defender, fully updated.

Comment: Tried turning off real-time protection but errors still occur - Access to the path C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Local\Temp\Attachment.pdf is denied.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend starting from reviewing the code and releasing all underlying COM objects instantly. Use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. This is particularly important if your add-in attempts to enumerate more than 256 Outlook items in a collection that is stored on a Microsoft Exchange Server. If you do not release these objects in a timely manner, you can reach the limit imposed by Exchange on the maximum number of items opened at any one time. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. You can read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article in MSDN.

For example:

```
foreach (Outlook.Attachment attach in getItem.Attachments)
```

The Attachments property returns an instance of the Attachments class which should be released after. Also each instance of the Attachment class stays alive until the method ends and GC runs.

Finally, I'd recommend using the **for** loop instead. Thus, you will be able to release every object instantly.

Comment: Any idea why the error only occurs with pdf attachments? The email archive being processed has messages with .doc, .docx. .txt  and other attachment file types but text can be extracted from all of these